# Searching through an array of an array of objects if a property exists?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, object

So based off of an ajax return, I am pushing an array of objects to another array with each unique search. From this, I am iterating through the most recent search array and rendering the objects. Doing this perfectly.

What I want to do now, is with each new search, check if a result's id === to an existing id within the array of array objects.

```
items = [
        [{id:1, name:blue},{id:21, name:red}],
        [{id:5, name:yellow},{id:232, name:green}]
        [{id:1, name:blue},{id:9, name:red}]
]
```

each of the nested arrays is an ajax response object that I pushed to the items array.

So I was wondering how I can look through the array of arrayed objects to see that items already has an id of 1 and i can exclude the object in items[0][0] with an id of 1 from being rendered.

I thought perhaps items.includes but not sure if that is valid?

Please let me know if any of this makes sense.

Comment: do you need just a check, or something to prevent something?

Comment: You can use [array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to return just the object, or [array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to just indicate its existence and work from there. Be aware `find` is ES6.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the arrays with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and return `true` if the given id is found.

```js
function checkId(id, array) {
    return array.some(function (a) {
        return a.some(function (b) {
            return b.id === id;
        });
    });
}

var items = [[{ id: 1, name: 'blue' }, { id: 21, name: 'red' }], [{ id: 5, name: 'yellow' }, { id: 232, name: 'green' }],[{ id: 1, name: 'blue' }, { id: 9, name: 'red' }]];

console.log(checkId(1, items));
console.log(checkId(42, items));
```

ES6

```js
function checkId(id, array) {
    return array.some(a => a.some(b => b.id === id));
}

var items = [[{ id: 1, name: 'blue' }, { id: 21, name: 'red' }], [{ id: 5, name: 'yellow' }, { id: 232, name: 'green' }],[{ id: 1, name: 'blue' }, { id: 9, name: 'red' }]];

console.log(checkId(1, items));
console.log(checkId(42, items));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to exclude the object, you can filter the arrays.

```
var filtered = items.map(function(arr) {
    return arr.filter(function(obj) {
        return obj.id !== 1
    });
});
```

Filtered will become:

```
[
    [{id:21, name:red}],
    [{id:5, name:yellow}, {id:232, name:green}],
    [{id:9, name:red}]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach` loop and if there is object with specified id you can use `splice` to remove it

```js
var items = [
  [{id:1, name:'blue'},{id:21, name:'red'}],
  [{id:5, name:'yellow'},{id:232, name:'green'}],
  [{id:1, name:'blue'},{id:9, name:'red'}]
]

function removeObj(ar, id) {
  ar.forEach(function(e) {
    e.forEach(function(a, i) {
      if(a.id == id) e.splice(i, 1);
    });
  });
}

removeObj(items, 1);
console.log(items);
```